# How do I choose the head and base fork in compare and review for git?

Tags: git, github

I had forked a repo 'test' of user1. I could make changes, commit and send pull requests to the main repo (i.e user1/test) earlier. But now, suddenly, when I click on Compare and Review, I get to choose head and base fork to compare with from only other forked repos (i.e other people who had forked 'test') and not the main repo (i.e user1/test). Hence, I am unable to send pull requests as well. What can be the issue?

Comment: Have you first [updated your copy](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) of the forked repository?

Comment: Yes, I had. I have written the solution that worked for me as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. The main repo test of user1 was private when I forked it and obviously my fork too was private. Recently user1/test was made public, because of which the private forks were all left as standalone repos (although the upstream still pointed to user1/test). 

I found the details here: https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/

To be able to compare and send pull requests to the main repo (user1/test) I had to make my fork public.
Hope this helps others.